# Can I use chrome.embeddedSearch in an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that overwrites the new tab. Now I want to write the chrome fakebox myself. When the user starts typing the input, I want to insert it into the chrome search bar.

In a new tab you can use chrome.embeddedSearch in the Chrome console.
If I now activate my extension I can't do this anymore.

javascript

```
console.log(chrome.embeddedSearch)
```

Result on new tab page without extension

```
{searchBox: {…}, newTabPage: {…}}
```

Result on new tab page with extension

```
undefined
```

I added to my manifest.json:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  }
```

Comment: No you can't use private internal APIs because those are exposed only to the built-in new tab page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome.embeddedSearch is deprecated. If I undestood you right, just use the standard "input" element and perform a search on submit.